# Backbone.js - realising template snippets belonging to the same view

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to build a basic web application with Backbone.JS and already encounter understanding issues in the very beginning.

I was thinking about the following HTML structure:

```
<script type="text/template" class="t_show">FOO</script>
static foobar
<script type="text/template" class="t_show">BAR</script>
```

where `static foobar` always gets rendered - `.t_show` however only, when the router matches `#show`.

That's my current backbone code:

`var v_show = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".client"),
    template: _.template( $( '.t_show' ).html() ),
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    },`

that kind of already works, however only renders the very first template-partial (`FOO`) and the static code (`static code`), but no (`BAR`).

Ling story short: How to realise template snippets belonging to the same view in Backbone?

Answer (score 1):

jquery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function will only return the html of the first matched element, so calling `_.template($('.t_show').html())` will only pass FOO to the template function.

There's a couple ways you could resolve this:

- If you want FOO and BAR to render right next to each other (styling aside), you can combine them into a single template.  I'm guessing this doesn't work for your use case or you wouldn't have asked about supporting multiple templates, but included it for completeness.
- Iterate through each `.t_show` and add the `html()` bits together, and pass the result to `_.template()`.  This also will show FOO and BAR next to each other.
- Assign each template to its own variable and then execute and render the templates separately.

That last option has the most flexibility as you can place the resulting html in different parts of your view if you wish, or you could re-render them individually which is handy if they're fairly isolated or either is kind of heavy to render.  That might look something like this:

```
fooTemplate: _.template($('.foo.t_show').html()),
barTemplate: _.template($('.bar.t_show').html()),
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.fooTemplate(this.model.attributes));
    this.$el.append(this.barTemplate(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
},
...
```